# Sql statement groupby with limiting condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

What am trying to do is to return all the records where the total count of truck owners is more than the specified limit
that is in the case below suppose the total limit is 3 i would like to fetch all the owners who have 3 or more trucks registered

so the query if the limit is 3 should only return metro trans as they have 3 or more trucks

This is my db structure

```
tbl_trucks
id   owner_id  .....
1    12
2    12
3    13
4    12

tbl_truck_owners
id   owner
12   metro trans
13   mush elec
```

How do i add the limit to my sql statement

THis is what i have tried

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(tbl_trucks.owner_id), tbl_truck_owners.owner
      FROM tbl_trucks
        LEFT JOIN tbl_truck_owners ON tbl_trucks.owner_id = tbl_truck_owners.id

        WHERE              //stuck at adding the limit

        GROUP BY owner_id"
```

How do i add the limit

Answer (score 4):

Use HAVING statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(tbl_trucks.owner_id), tbl_truck_owners.owner
FROM tbl_trucks
LEFT JOIN tbl_truck_owners ON tbl_trucks.owner_id = tbl_truck_owners.id
GROUP BY owner_id
HAVING COUNT(tbl_trucks.owner_id) >= 3
```